# send non-ascii word in request post?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, request, ascii

I want to send this word `"Réfugié"`to the site, but when I send it with the UTF-8 encode I don't get the result (`'r\xc3\xa9fugi\xc3\xa9'`)

But the string must be correct (`'r\xe9fugi\xe9'`).

How can I do that? I tried using string and the encoding and encoding for UTF-8 did not work. Latin-1 did not work either.

Comment: Show us some code you've tried. Also, maybe look at `urllib` (depending on your version, maybe `urllib.parse`) for `urlencode` and associated `quote` or `quote_plus` functions; you can define how the "POST" parems are encoded to support HTTP/1.1 standards.

Comment: # -*- coding: latin1 -*-
import requests
url = "http://www.website.com/chercher/"
search_word = "réfugié"
payload = {'q' : search_word}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)